# Constructing tree from a given HashMap

Tags: java, loops

I want to traverse a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map` and constructing a tree from this map. For example I have following map: 1=[2,3], 2=[3,4], 3=[1,5], 4=[2,5], 5=[1,4]. What I want to do is traversing this map with following manner:

```
public static Tree getTree (HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> paths) {

    Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree(-1);
    Integer node;

    for (int i = 1; i <= paths.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < paths.get(i).size(); j++) {

            node = paths.get(i).get(j);
            tree.addLeaf(i, node);

            for(int k = 0; k < paths.get(node).size(); k++) {

                tree.addLeaf(node, paths.get(node).get(k));
                node = paths.get(node).get(k);

                // now I have to go to paths.get(node) and receive its ArrayList

                for (int t = 0; t < paths.get(node).size(); t++) {

                      tree.addLeaf(node, paths.get(node).get(t));
                      node = paths.get(node).get(t);


                }

            }
        }
    }

    return tree;
}
```

If the new node is equal to one of its ancestors the node should be added to the tree but should not be traversed anymore. I want to make this operation dynamically.

Comment: mhmm, I am struggling to understand your end goal. please elaborate.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand what your probem is if you posted actual code reproducing it, rather than non-compiling pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion to traverse map, pass current state as arguments to recursive method:

```
public void step(Map<Integer, List<Integer>> tree, List<Integer> nodes, Integer key) {
    if (nodes.contains(key)) {
        // skip node which we already processed
        return;
    }
    nodes.add(key);

    List<Integer> children = tree.get(key);
    // add sanity checks here if you expect inconsistent data
    for (Integer child : children) {
        step(tree, nodes, child);
    }
}
```

Now the hardest part here is to find which node is root. Since you use map there is no order of map entries. So I leave this part to you:

```
step(map, tempList, 1);
```